# Highlight Rows in Excel Using VBA Code to Find Cells With Values Ending in Particular Terms

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel document with lists of contact information that was typed by hand from paper contact sheets. As such, there are many typos (human error). Because the lists are so long, I don't have time to look through the lists by hand to correct obvious errors. The most important piece of contact information for each row is the email address, which if it's spelled wrong, I have no way of contacting the person.

I used a macro from a different user's answer to highlight rows containing common errors in the domain name portion of the email address, such as "@gamil.com", ".copm", ".cpm", "@hormail.com", "@yahool.com", "@yaho.com", "fmail.com", "@vergin.net".

(To give credit where credit is due, the code I started with came from user [me how](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140173/me-how) who is amazing at macros, and I wish I had a way to ask him directly to help with this, but I don't have the "reputation" to make comments yet. The question that I found this code as an answer to was [Finding Multiple text in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251379/finding-multiple-text-in-excel).)

```
Sub HighlightRowsBasedOnArrayCondition()
Dim searchTerms As Variant
searchTerms = Array("@gamil.com", ".copm", ".cpm", "@hormail.com", "@yahool.com", "@yaho.com", "fmail.com", "@vergin.net")

ReDim rowsToHighlight(0) As String

Dim allRange As Range
Set allRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Dim cell As Range, word As Variant
For Each cell In allRange
For Each word In searchTerms
If InStr(1, cell, word, vbTextCompare) Then
rowsToHighlight(UBound(rowsToHighlight)) = CStr(cell.Row)
ReDim Preserve rowsToHighlight(UBound(rowsToHighlight) + 1)
End If
Next word
Next cell
ReDim Preserve rowsToHighlight(UBound(rowsToHighlight) - 1)

Dim v As Long
For v = UBound(rowsToHighlight) To LBound(rowsToHighlight) Step -1
Rows(rowsToHighlight(v)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Next
End Sub
```

**I would like to better specify these terms as being the end of the cell value** so that I can then have the macro highlight email addresses that end in "@yahoo.co" and "@gmail.co" so that I can catch it when the ".com" is incomplete. Obviously, if I were to use the current version of the macro with these terms, it will highlight not only those email errors that I'm looking for but also those with the completed domain name. **Can someone please tell me if it is possible to specify that the search terms are the ending of the cell values? If so, can you please guide me as to how to alter this code to do so?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this should be pretty easy.  Right now your code is simply checking for the *presence* of `word` in `cell`.

```
If InStr(1, cell, word, vbTextCompare)
```

If you want to make sure it's at the *end* only, then you can use the `Right` function:

```
If Right(cell, Len(word)) = word Then
```

Modify to ignore case-sensitivity and possible trailing spaces:

```
If Trim(LCase(right(cell, Len(word)))) = Trim(LCase(word)) Then
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked quite well! And I think I can apply these terms to more macro codes in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use Conditional Formatting. No VBA required, just a fancy formula that took me way to long to come up with. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

And here's the formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(C2,LEFT(C2,LEN(C2)-LEN(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11))&Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11))
```

Note that in Excel proper, that's an array formula, but in Conditional Formatting you just enter it normally.

Comment: Thank you! I would recommend this to others with one or two projects to make this work for. I myself will be dealing with several lists every month, so I need a faster way to add the formatting, with fewer clicks and less data entry. If I were hesitant to use VBA, your solution would be the best!